# How to add the /_vti_bin/Admin.asmx webservice as a service reference in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to use the Admin webservice of SharePoint 2007 within a console application. So I add a new service reference to my project pointing to `http://<central administration>/_vti_bin/Admin.asmx`. But instead of creating the proxy class it ends in an error. Regarding the error message, the service cannot be accessed due to an authentication problem.

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Also trying to access the page via web browser results in a redirect to an error page. I can access all other webservices via browser as well as via Visual Studio.

I've also had a look at the add service reference menu, but couldn't find option to pass any credentials.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the right URL. Try using the following:

```
http://CentralAdministration:Port/_vti_adm/Admin.asmx
```

Take a look at [Nick Swan's blog](http://weblog.vb-tech.com/nick/archive/2006/03/07/1472.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Anonymous access and Enable Integrated Windows autehntication in IIS.

Comment: Integrated Windows autehntication was already enabled and enabling anonymous access didn't solve the problem.